# Finding velocity position and distance from time

Tags: integration

sorry if this is a repeat question. I've been given the question:
Determine the particles velocity, position, and distance traveled when $t = 8\,\mathrm{s}$.
The initial conditions are:

$a=(2t-1)$

$s=9\,\mathrm{m}$ and $v=4\,\mathrm{m/s}$ when $t=0$

So far I've got:
$v=123\,\mathrm{m/s}$

$s=692\,\mathrm{m}$

distance = $480\,\mathrm{m}$

I think both S and the distance are wrong but I can't see what I've done wrong. Please help

Comment: What work have you done so far to get those answers?

Comment: Please mention your steps that led you to these answers.

Comment: I used completely the wrong formula's. I used $V_a=V_i+at$ and i got the first constant wrong in the velocity formula which extended to my formula for S. Thanks for your willingness to help though I think the answer below has solved me problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a(t) = 2t - 1$ but then, $v(t) = t^2 - t + c$, where $c$ is come constant.
$v(0) = 4 = 0^2 - 0 + c$, then, $c = 4.$
Now, $v(t) = t^2 -t + 4.$
In the end, $s(t) = \frac{t^3}{3} - \frac{t^2}{2} + 4t + d$, where $d$ is some constant.
$s(0) = 9 = d$ (why?)
Then, $s(t) = \frac{t^3}{3} - \frac{t^2}{2} + 4t + 9$.
Now calculate $s(8),v(8),a(8).$

Comment: Thanks for the response. So using than can I take v(8)=60m/s, s(8) = 180m and my distance is correct? Also I don't have to then find out v asin v=60/8 do I as v(8) is a function of time?

Comment: yes, in fact that forumla you said is just the medium velocity, it is a measure of media, is not the instant velocity, that is given by the function $v(t)$.

Comment: awesome, thank-you very much for your help

Comment: by media I mean average, I think that the term "media" does not exist in english. I am sorry.

Comment: i got what you meant and it's helpful so thanks